# What are the best and proper ways to create and design professional php database reports?

Tags: php, database, tabs, pagination, report

I hope you are all fine.

I would like to ask the expert php developers about the best and proper way to create and design professional php database reports.

How to show them properly and display them in a well-formated pages in case reports have many tables and data and how to view them in tabs and pages indicating the number of data in each page and the total data displayed and having some summary data in each page ?

I use html tables or divs to design the container of the data and I fill it using php code but it will be a boring and dull process in case of difficult and sophitecated data.

I am sure there are other good ways but I do not find suitable information or practical examples and some of them are not free or open-source.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I' having trouble seeing a real question in here. PHP is not a markup language in itself; it just can *generate* markup like HTML (or PDF files, or XML files, or whatever). Therefore, it's a bit unclear which part of the process you are looking for. Also, does it have to be PHP based? It might be easier to find a non-PHP-based report creating solution that can read stuff from mySQL databases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My question is what is the best way to view the reports with advanced options like printing, exporting to different data types, tabbing, paging and so on if I have some hundred page reports. My Development tools are HTML, Javascript for Client-Side and PHP for Server-Side and the Database Engine is Sybase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like Pekka, the question is rather vague. If you are looking for reporting tools, have a look at phplens, Crystal Reports, Pentaho reporting, Agata report, MS Access....